# Добавить узел в бинарное дерево

Tags: c++, бинарное-дерево

Мне нужно добавить узел в бинарное дерево, чтобы вышло так: "Binary Tree is a kind of orderly table". Условие задачи:

> "Сформировать дерево синтаксического разбора предложений "Binary Tree is a kind of table". Добавить узел, чтобы получить предложение "Binary Tree is a kind of orderly table".

Вот мой код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include<conio.h> 
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<string.h> 
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int info;
    char A[256];
    node *l, *r;
};

node *root = NULL;

void push(int a, node **t)
{
    if ((*t) == NULL) 
    {
        (*t) = new node;  
        (*t)->info = a;  
        (*t)->l = (*t)->r = NULL;  
        return;
    }

    if (a>(*t)->info) push(a, &(*t)->r); 
    else push(a, &(*t)->l); 
}
void pushchar(char b, node **t)
{
    if ((*t) == NULL)
    {
        (*t) = new node;
        (*t)->A[256] = b;
        (*t)->l = (*t)->r = NULL;
        return;
    }
    pushchar(b, &(*t)->l);
}


void print(node *t)
{
    if (t)
    {
        print(t->l);
        if (t->info) cout<< t->info<<' ';
        print(t->r);
    }

}
void printchar(node *t)
{
    if (t)
    {
        print(t->l);
        if (t->A) cout<<t->A<<' ';
        printchar(t->r);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int B[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };    
    char *A[256] = { "Binary", "Three", "is", "a", "kind", "of", "table" };
    cout<<"Our digits:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        cout<<B[i]; 
        push(B[i], &root);
    }
    cout<<" Our tree:\n";
    print(root);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        pushchar(*A[i], &root);
    }
    printchar(root);

    cout << '\n';
    cout << "tree 2\n";
    print(root);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Tree и three - это надо заменить содержание узла или это опечатка?

Comment: @I.S.M. опечатка, извини.

Comment: Я надеюсь, «узёл» — тоже опечатка?

Comment: @VladD, так вы поможете или как? :)

Comment: @Alex: Честно говоря, я не совсем понял задание. Я не в курсе, что такое «дерево синтаксического разбора предложений» (возможно, у вас есть где-то формальная грамматика?)

Comment: @VladD: Сейчас кину тебе на хохлятском языке: Сформувати дерево синтаксичного розбору речення: “Бінарне дерево є різновидом таблиць”. Додати вузол, щоб одержати речення: “Бінарне дерево є різновидом упорядкованої таблиці”. Вивести проміжний та остаточний результати.

Comment: @Alex: Нi, так само незрозумiло :(